# MySQL sequential procedure call with transactions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, mysql-5.7

How do transactions within stored procedures affect each other? Is it possible to use this structure or will the second procedure interrupt the transaction of the first one?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure() begin
    ...
    CALL some_procedure1();
    CALL some_procedure2();
    ...
end
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure1() begin
    START TRANSACTION;
    ...
    COMMIT;
end
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure2() begin
    START TRANSACTION;
    ...
    COMMIT;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one thread for a given MySQL session, so the procedures run serially.

`some_procedure1()` commits its transaction before it returns, and that must finish before `some_procedure2()` is called.